# what should i use for namespace on jquery widgets?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, namespaces, widget

I'm reading through the beginners documentation on creating plugins using the jquery ui widget factory.  It takes a named spaced name:

```
 $.widget( 'dp.list', {
```

My question is... do you HAVE to have a namespace?  Are there conventions (buckets) for what kind of namespace my plugin should belong to?  Is there a list somewhere or can I just make up anything that I want?

Answer (score 1):

A good start would be to look at the jQuery UI library. The names are highly intuitive and meaningful. The name represent the ui widget that will be created on widget instantiation.

jQuery widget framework can be treated as a tool to mimic OO like functionality.

> It provides a flexible base for building complex, stateful plugins
>   with a consistent API. It is designed not only for plugins that are
>   part of jQuery UI, but for general consumption by developers who want
>   to create object-oriented components without reinventing common
>   infrastructure. --http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory

The namespace can be meaningful if you have multiple modules and you want to avoid collision as well as provide meaningful classification

```
$.widget('<module_name>.widgetName', {..prototype..} )
```

eg

```
$.widget('cart.paymentProcess', {}) , $.widget('cart.shippingCalculator', {})
$.widget('catalog.productReviews',{}), $.widget('catalog.productPricing',{}) etc
```

I would also recommend reading these helpful questions to understand namespacing issues in jQuery widgets:

[JQuery UI: How to call a widget function with its namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739525/jquery-ui-how-to-call-a-widget-function-with-its-namespace)

[Extending jQueryUI widgets without conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697274/extending-jqueryui-widgets-without-conflicts)

Comment: How do namespaces help with collisions, when the namespace can't be used when calling the plugin?  If you name the widget 'cart.shippingCalculator', you still call it on a jQuery object as just 'shippingCalculator'.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is personal. But:

1. The namespace should let you understand the "meaning" of the plugin
2. Try to not use something like "usethispluginforsearhthingsinsidethedom" ;)

Answer (score 0):

The namespace is your way of identifying your plugin. Commonly you want to use a few words that easily describe what your plugin does, but keeping it fairly unique.

By describing your plugin you tell your users briefly what they can expect the plugin to do, but if the name is common, you may come across another plugin by that name and that can cause a mess of problems.

You also don't want a creative name that doesn't describe it because then its unclear what the plugin does.